# Cant center align stuff using materialize

Tags: css, html, materialize, center-align

I've been using [MaterializeCSS](http://materializecss.com/), and I'm having some trouble to centralize stuff, I have the following snippet, and tried a lot of stuff, but I can't figure it out a way to centralize it because it always left aligns it

How do I do it?

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css';
```

```html
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m5 profile-inner center-block">
          <img class="circle responsive-img perfil-icon" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/profileicon/600.png">
          <br><span class="center-align"style="font-size: 2.5rem">TyG Yeux</span><br>
          
          <span style="font-size: 1.5rem">Level 50</span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `center-align` instead of `center-block`. `center-block` is suitable to used for centering image itself. But, currently you want to center from Parent container, by such need to use center-align to align all child to center

```css
@import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css';
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m5 profile-inner center-align">
          <img class="circle responsive-img perfil-icon" src="http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/profileicon/600.png">
          <br><span class="center-align"style="font-size: 2.5rem">TyG Yeux</span><br>
          
          <span style="font-size: 1.5rem">Level 50</span>
        </div>
```